# startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges getting triggered after traveling distance of more than 3-5km

Tags: ios, swift, geolocation, location, geofencing

Im working on some POC where in i want a location update even when the app is terminated, im using the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`, where is as per [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423531-startmonitoringsignificantlocati)(Apps can expect a notification as soon as the device moves 500 meters or more from its previous notification.) Where as in my case the location updates are not triggered exactly after 500m(it is able to trigger the background location update sometimes at 3km or 9km etc, which is not consistant). So is there any way that we can figure out that user has travelled exactly 500m or something to trigger the location update?

Is there any way that we can make the app to get the location update even on terminated state at particular distance travelled by user?
Thanks in advance.

My POC is something related to geoFencing where in after traveling user with certain distance, i would be changing the regions that user should be monitored, but in foreground/background its fine because if i use [distanceFilter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter), i could able to have control with me to realter/rearrange the geoFencing to be observed, but it doesnt work in background, so i had to use the `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` to have the location update even on terminated state.

Comment: do you need just notification on 500 meters or some logic to be triggered?

Comment: Its not the notification to be triggered, 
its actually, I need the location `didUpdateLocations` to be triggered, which happens when ever we receive a location update. 
So depending on the user's current location, i alter my code to update the geofences to be monitored.